# Cannot satisfy RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec3

I have this rspec code:

```
let(:valid_attributes) {
    {name: "Sample Product"}
  } 

  describe "#index" do
    it "should give a collection of products" do
      product = Product.create! valid_attributes
      get :index, :format => :json
      expect(response.status).to eq(200)
      expect(response).to render_template("api/products/index")
      expect(assigns(:products)).to eq([product])
    end
  end
```

And it controller:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

But the controller code still doesn't satisfy the spec. What is wrong here.

Here is the failure message:

> Failures:
>
> 1) Api::ProductsController#index should give a collection of
>   products
>        Failure/Error: expect(assigns(:products)).to eq([product])
>
> ```
>    expected: [#<Product id: 3, name: "Sample Product", created_at: "2016-06-15 05:10:50", updated_at: "2016-06-15 05:10:50">]
>         got: nil
>
>    (compared using ==)
>  # ./spec/controllers/api/products_controller_spec.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```
>
> Finished in 0.05106 seconds (files took 1.89 seconds to load) 1
>   example, 1 failure

Answer (score 0):

You have:

```
get :index, :format => :json
```

I assume you should have:

```
get :index, :format => :html
```

By default, rails returns html, and you didn't specify otherwise in your `index` action.

Comment: I specified in my controller that I want to render it as json. And I think I got this failure because of this line of code `expect(assigns(:products)).to eq([product])`. Because when I commented this out it passes the spec. But I need that line to test that I am assigning a value for that said `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

- `assign` checks that an instance variable was set
- and `products` should be created in database (use `let!`(with bang) for it), then:

in your controller:

```
def index
  @products = Product.all # `@products` should be present
end
```

in rspec:

```
let(:valid_attributes) {{ name: 'Sample Product' }}
let!(:product) { Product.create!(valid_attributes) } # use `!` here

describe "#index" do
  before { get :index, format :json }

  it 'should give a collection of products' do
    expect(assigns(:products)).to eq([product])
  end
end
```